# Shifting the subcaption in subfigure

Tags: subcaption

I have a subfigure in which I want to shift one of the figures to the left, but when I shift it the caption is in its place. what should I do?

Here is what I have in latex:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\hspace{-4cm}
\subfigure[1]{
\includegraphics[scale=1]{1.eps}
\label{fig:1}
}
\\
\subfigure[2]{
\hspace{-4cm}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{2.eps}
\label{fig:2}
}
\label{fig:fig}
\caption[fig:fig]{caption}
\end{figure*}
```

The problem is with figure 2

Comment: It's quite unclear why you should use `\hskip{-4cm}` to begin with.

Comment: Your problem is better understood if you provide a complete MWE (instead of snippets). You are using `\begin{figure*}`. Are you using 2 column format? Do you want figures to come one below the other? Are you using `subfigure` package? If so, kindly consider using `subfig` instead as the former is obsolete. Bottom line: MWE please.